# x86 assembly tricks to get more GPRs

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote an assembly program that needs 5 GPRs on x86-64 which works fine. But I am trying to port it to 32-bit x86. Compiler complains about the impossibility to use 5 GPRs.

Code for x86-64 is below:

```
  __asm__("mov %0,%%r8\n\t"
          "mov %1,%%r10\n\t"
          "lfence\n\t"
          "rdtsc\n\t"
          "mov %%eax,%%edi\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "mov (%%r8), %%r8\n\t"
          "lfence\n\t"
          "rdtsc\n\t"
          "sub %%edi, %%eax\n\t"
          "mov %%eax, (%%r10)\n\t"
          :
          :"r"(head),"r"(time_buf)
          :"eax","edx","edi","r8","r10"
          );
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T9400

Comment: No way if you have run out of registers. You need to spill some values to memory. Another way is spilling to SSE/AVX registers but I don't think the performance is any better unless you try to vectorize the code. You can get maximum 7 GPRs in 32-bit mode using `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: You can push `%ebx`, `%ebp` and pop them at the end, in the asm statement itself. The compiler will have no awareness of their use in this context, of course. But the answer given is probably what you really want. As it stands, your code isn't correct - you can't know if your clobbered registers alias `%0` or `%1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need 5 registers, you only need 4.  The registers EAX and EDX are clobbered by the RDTSC instruction, so that's two. You need another register to hold value EAX from the first RDTSC instruction. That's three.  The fourth register is the for the `head` pointer.  The other register you're using you don't need, it's not necessary to compute or store the elapsed time in the `asm` statement. You can do that in ordinary C/C++ code.

I'd rewrite your asm statement to be something like this:

```
unsigned
foo(void *head) {
    unsigned time_start, time_end;

    __asm__("lfence\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "mov (%1), %1\n\t"
        "lfence\n\t"
        "rdtsc"
        : "=r" (time_start), "+r" (head), "=a" (time_end)
        :
        : "edx"
        );
    return time_end - time_start;
}
```

This asm statement lets the compiler pick the registers where possible. The use of the EAX and EDX are fixed by the RDTSC instruction, but the registers used to to hold `time_start` time stamp and the `head` pointer are left to the compiler to choose.

Aside from using one less register, my example asm statement has the advantage of working both in 32-bit and 64-bit without modifications.